# Какие файлы кроме txt может редактировать java? можно например создать и редактировать doc, docx?

Tags: java, office

Знаю что java может создать txt файлы через стандартную библиотеку, а  возможно ли работать с файлами офисного пакета (копировать и перемещать не в счет)

Comment: Офисные форматы от Майкрософт, например .docx проприетарный стандарт.
За его использование без заключения договора с правообладателем могут предъявить претензии.

Comment: Укажите хотя бы платформу, о которой речь. JAVA сама по себе ничего такого не умеет, но для некоторых платформ существуют библиотеки для разных форматов, которые не являются частью ОС (как упомянутый вами TXT, к примеру).

Comment: Не знаю что вы называете стандартной библиотекой, но можно создать. Другое дело, что работать стандартной библиотекой будет крайне тяжело. Лучше скачать библиотеку для работы с офисом

Comment: Любой файл - это просто набор байт. Java способна записывать байты в файл, а значит она автоматически может создавать файлы абсолютно любых форматов (даже тех, которые ещё не изобрели). Вопрос только в удобстве: для одних форматов могут быть облегчающие работу библиотеки, для других придётся собирать байтики вручную

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для работы с документами, созданными в пакете MS Office на основе Office Open XML (OOXML) формата, существует библиотека [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

- [Обзор данной библиотеки со ссылками на примеры работы с Excel и Word документами](https://javadevblog.com/obzor-biblioteki-apache-poi-rabota-s-prilozheniyami-paketa-microsoft-office-v-java.html)
- [Пример работы с Excel-таблицей](https://java-online.ru/java-excel.xhtml)
- [Пример работы с Word документом (англ.)](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-word-with-apache-poi)